# How to disallow Task from being interrupted by await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Coming from JavaScript I am used to the fact that code execution does not interleave, with await expressions being an exception, which define fixed re-entry points.
The .NET asynchrony semantics appear to be different though: During every call of `Thread.Sleep`, a `Task` waiting to be run jumps in and performs work. Then, **on return of of the `Sleep` call, the `Task`'s computation is interrupted immediately**, as the code below demonstrates.

How can I achieve atomic execution of the loop? (Without locks or the like; assuming a single thread)

```
static async Task RunExperiment()
{
    var task = DoNotInterruptMe();
    Console.WriteLine("sleep...");
    Thread.Sleep(60);
    Console.WriteLine("sleep...");
    Thread.Sleep(60);
    Console.WriteLine($"Interrupted, because i={i}");
    Console.WriteLine("sleep...");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Interrupted again, because i={i}");
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine("task.Status: "+task.Status);
}

private static int i;

static async Task DoNotInterruptMe()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I: delay...");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("I: working...");
    int j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 1<<30; i++)
    {
        j *= i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("I: finished work");
}
```

Run above using

```
RunExperiment().Wait();
```

I am using `Thread.Sleep` here, but `await Task.Delay(60)` behaves just alike.

#### Sample output:

```
I: delay...
sleep...
sleep...
I: working...
Interrupted, because i=358449
sleep...
Interrupted again, because i=8598631
I: finished work
task.Status: RanToCompletion
```

Comment: Are you running this code in a console app?  Remember, **await works differently in a console app than in a winforms app**.

Comment: If you don't want your main code to continue until the function is complete, why not declare a simple function and just call it?

Comment: Also, your belief that Thread.Sleep does not put a thread to sleep is plainly wrong; read the documentation: it clearly states that it genuinely sleeps the thread and does not pump the message loop. **There must be something here that you are misunderstanding.** You say "assuming a single thread". Examine that assumption. Make your `WriteLine` calls print out the current thread id and report back what your observations are.

Comment: @EricLippert I already did so, I get 1 every time for Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Comment: @EricLippert Actually, the thread changed after `await Task.Delay`, thanks!

Comment: @xoxox C#/.Net behaves essentially the same as [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) that you are likely familiar with as you know JavaScript... also boundaries between threads in C# are way less protected/defined than between main script and workers in JavaScript...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your usage of Console.WriteLine, I assume this is a console app.  **Await behaves differently in console apps than it does in windows forms apps**.

Let's take a step back and say what `await` does:

- Check to see if the awaitable (a task, in this case) is complete.
- If it is completed abnormally, throw that exception, and have the current thread handle it.
- If it is completed normally, fetch its value, if any, and keep going on the current thread.
- If it is not complete, schedule the remainder of the method to run **as the continuation of the task, bound to the current thread context** when the task is complete. Then return to your caller.

It's that last bit that you are confused about.  **In a console application the continuation of the task may be scheduled onto a worker thread by the default console context**.

In a windows forms app, the default context is to schedule the continuation on the current apartment, which we can do because we post a message to that apartment's message loop that causes the continuation to run. But there is no message loop in a console app.

Let's demonstrate this by rewriting your program:

```
static void Write(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}:{s}");
}
```

And now we change every other `Console.WriteLine` to call `Write`, and run your program and we see:

```
1:I: delay...
1:sleep...
1:sleep...
6:I: working...
1:Interrupted, because i=4061320
1:sleep...
1:Interrupted again, because i=26763596
6:I: finished work
6:task.Status: RanToCompletion
```

Thread 1 starts the delay, and we then schedule the remainder of that workflow to run when the delay is complete.  We immediately return and sleep.  Meanwhile, the delay finishes and signals the task to run the remainder of its workflow, **which it does on thread 6**.

Back on thread 1, the sleeps finish and we discover that `i` has been updated -- I note that you forgot to make `i` volatile, but luckily we got the update.

Thread 1 then awaits the task associated with the asynchronous workflow, which is still running on thread 6, so it returns to its caller, and signs up the remainder of its workflow as the continuation of that task.

That task then completes on thread 6, and the continuation is now ready to be scheduled **onto a worker thread**. But thread 6 is now idle, so it gets scheduled and runs the remainder of the task.

This is to be expected in a console application. **If you need fine-grained control over what thread a continuation is scheduled to run on, then you need to learn about how thread contexts work.**  Or, write an application that has a message pump, and the default context will keep everything on the same thread.